# How to generate an array for each input value from textBox in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textBox which will allow me to enter the building name and after I click on 'Add Building' button, it takes the value and passes it to the next page.So, in my screenshot below, the values  'AbsBuildingOne' and 'AbsBuildingTwo' comes from the textBox input.So, currently I am able to pass a single value from  the textBox to the next page, but I am not able to understand if I want to enter the second building how do I save the previous value in this page and add the second value below it. I guess I have to do it with arrays, but I am not able to figure it out how to proceed.

[image: building]

Currently, my code looks as shown below for passing the single value.I have added a state:

```
   this.state = {
                 textBoxValue: '',
                };
```

So, in my textBox the onUpdateHandler function looks like this:

```
 onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler = (inputData) => {
    this.setState({ textBoxValue: inputData.value});
  }
```

My textBox component looks like this.Its a custom textBox designed for the project:

```
         <SceTextBox
            placeholder='Enter Building Name'
            id='AddBuilding'
            type='buildingName'
            maxLength='40'
            onTextUpdatedHandler={this.onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler.bind(this)}
            forceValidate={this.state.forceValidate}
            validator={app.appUtil.validator}
            isError={this.state.textBoxEmptyError}
            errorMsg={this.errorMessage}
          />
```

So, currently I am passing the value of `this.state.textBoxValue` to my next component where the building names are displayed.

So, how do I proceed with multiple values and how do I save all the building names? Also, I have to delete the building name when i click on close icon. So do I have to work with push/pop in array? Someone please guide me with this.

**Edit 1:**

My new state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
      buildingNames: {
        [id++]: ''
      }
    };
```

Both my functions are:

```
  onClickAddBuildingButtonHandler = () => {
    const { buildingNames } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      buildingNames: {
        ...buildingNames,
        [id++]:''
      }
    });

    if (!this.state.selectedOptions) {
      this.setState({ isRadioEmptyError: true });

      if (!this.state.buildingNames.id) {
        this.setState({ textBoxEmptyError: true });
      }
    }

    if (this.state.selectedOptions && this.state.buildingNames) {
      this.props.navigateToAddBuilding(this.state.buildingNames);
    }
  }





  onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler = (inputData) => {
    const { buildingNames } = this.state;
    this.setState({ 
      buildingNames:{
        ...buildingNames,
        [inputData.id] : inputData.value
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of values from a `textarea` you can use the `this.state.value.split('\n')` to separate split the string on each new line producing an array for you.

Below is a very simple example demonstrating its effectiveness. Just type in the textarea and look at the console. Once you make a new line you'll see a second element appears in the array.

```js
function handleKeyUp() {
  const textarea = document.getElementById('my-ta');
  console.log(textarea.value.split('\n'));
}
```

```html
<textarea id='my-ta' onKeyUp='handleKeyUp()'></textarea>
```

EDIT #1:

Here is a [Code Sandbox Example 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/94v7q0yzqw) demonstrating how it is done. Type in the textarea, make a new line and type some more and then hit the toggle button. You'll see the values displayed and if you toggle back they're in the textarea still.

EDIT #2:

So here is another example of how something can be done. This will show you how to add an item to a list. [Code Sandbox Example 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/13jwq94q34)

I'm going to leave it up to you to combine the two methods.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.The issue is the names can have multiple words. So when I enter my first building name, it can be of 2 or more words. Then when I navigate back to my previous page to enter the 2nd building name, both should be saved.

Comment: If you want to save state between components you're going to need to either use a state management system such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/), or save the state in a component higher in the tree. If your project doesn't already have something like redux or  mobx I'd advice lifting state to a higerh component. Here is the offical react guide for that: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Yeah, redux is not being used here. So, is there no other option like storing the data in state as passing as props to the other, I mean with state and props this won't be possible? Sorry, I am not aware of how to proceed, was just trying to do it from states.

Comment: Yes, that is what lifting state is all about. If you have two sibling components that need to be aware of the same state then you need to store the state in a parent of both and pass the information to them through props.

Comment: @pranami I made a quick and direct example to demonstrate for you. The link is at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration. I checked that, but in the demo what is happening is I am updating the value, but what I want is I want to add a new value every time I click on the toggle button.I want it to be a list of values every time its added.

Comment: So you want a button that adds an input field to a ul>li that you can then type in? Oh I see your picture now... I thought your question was how to maintain state between components.

Comment: yeah Kyle.Actually when I click the 'Add Another Building' button, it should again redirect to the previous page and show up the text box to enter the building. Then when I add the building, it should be the next item in the added building page.

Comment: You should be able to combine those two methods to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Kyle, I have tried the way you suggested, but its failing for some reason. I have added the 2 functions in an edit above. Can you please check once what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Error message? Some direction? That's just two functions without even showing their implementation.  How is inputData being passed into the second function? Is it the element itself? If so you'll need to do `inputData.target.id`. Where did the radio button stuff come from? Wasn't in your original post.

Comment: Actually my page redirects to a new page, so earlier I passed the updated value of the textInput which I saved in the state. And it was working fine.So I din't add it the code.Now since I changed the state to an object, its failing, so `this.props.navigateToAddBuilding(this.state.buildingNames);` is where I am passing the state value to the next page.I guess I am not passing it the correct way.Since everything was working as expected with a single value,I didn't add those things in the code. The error message is that `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #31; `

Comment: It's because of `this.props.navigateToAddBuilding(this.state.buildingNames);`. So, how do I pass the whole list of building names as parameter inside the props?

Comment: If you want I can post all the files, but it would become messier, so I didn't post all of it.